# Showing pairwise chromatical equivalence

Tags: graph-theory

Show that the following graphs are pairwise chromatically equivalent. 
[image: 1]

Comment: How far have you advanced on this problem?

Comment: Not much, i'm not familiar with the topic yet. I'm hoping for a simple hint to start.